# Can't use def keyword in build.gradle.kts --> error: "Unresolved reference: def"

Tags: function, build.gradle

When I use this code in build.gradle.kts(:app), it gives this error: Unresolved reference: def

```
def apikeyPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("apikey.properties")
def apikeyPro = new Properties()
apikeyPro.load(new FileInputStream(apikeyPropertiesFile))
```

How can I use "def" in gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `def` keyword comes from the Groovy language. This language is used when writing any `*.gradle` script.

And `*.gradle.kts` uses the Kotlin language, so you should use that language. The counterpart of the `def` keyword is the `val` or `var` keywords in Kotlin.

Just use those keywords instead of `def`.